# What is the difference/relation between kernel name and OS name?

Tags: kernel

What is the difference/relation between kernel name and OS name?
Are they always the same thing?

For example, I am puzzled at the outputs:

```
-bash-4.1$ uname -s
Linux
-bash-4.1$ uname -o
GNU/Linux
```

What is difference between "GNU/Linux" and "Linux"?

Comment: Slow Saturday night? Asking all these `uname` questions? 8-)

Comment: yes, I am fighting with uname.

Comment: Related : http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/250506/66803

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the `uname` Wikipedia page titled: [Uname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname) there's a very nice table that shows the output of `uname` with all of its switches for just about every Unix I've ever heard of.

*excerpt of table*

[image: ss#1]
    [image: ss#2]
    [image: ss#3]

If you look at the output it would imply that `-s` shows the name of the kernel, while `-o` shows the name of the operating system.

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering how uname distinguishes kernel name and OS name?

Comment: @Tim - do you mean technically how it does it or what's the difference?

Comment: The latter, i.e. difference in concepts, but I believe it  is also what the implementation of uname follows

Comment: @Tim - well the kernel's the kernel. Take a look at this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(computing). The OS is a combination of a kernel + additional applications & libraries.